# Using an ifelse() statement for datetime observations within a given interval

Tags: r, datetime, if-statement, posixct

I would like to assign a value to the `df$lamp_intensity` vector depending on a specific time interval within `df$date`. If a given observation is outside of this interval, I would like to assign an `NA`. Once I get this first bit of code working, I plan on nesting a bunch of `ifelse()` statements to handle multiple time intervals. I think I'm pretty close, but I could definitely use a hand.

Thank you!

**Here's my data:**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1504787028, 1504787030, 1504787031, 1504787032, 1504787033, 1504787034, 1504787035, 1504787036, 1504787037, 1504787038), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ppm = c(0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.0009765625, 0.00146484375)), .Names = c("date", "ppm"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df$lamp_intensity <- ifelse(df$date >= as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:51",
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") && ## using '&' generates an error message
    date <= as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:55",
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"), 0, NA)

head(df, 10)
```

The solution would assign `0` for `df$lamp_intensity` rows between `2017-09-07 12:23:51` and `2017-09-07 12:23:55`

Comment: `date <= as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:55"` should be `df$date <= as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:55"`. That's why you're getting the error with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `cut` function instead. For example:

```
df$lamp_intensity = cut(df$date, 
                        breaks=as.POSIXct(c("2017-09-07 12:23:42","2017-09-07 12:23:55",
                                            "2017-09-07 12:24:02", "2017-09-07 12:24:31"), tz="UTC"),
                        labels=c(0,1,2))

                  date          ppm lamp_intensity
 1 2017-09-07 12:23:48 0.0009765625              0
 2 2017-09-07 12:23:50 0.0009765625              0
 3 2017-09-07 12:23:51 0.0009765625              0
 4 2017-09-07 12:23:52 0.0009765625              0
 5 2017-09-07 12:23:53 0.0009765625              0
 6 2017-09-07 12:23:54 0.0009765625              0
 7 2017-09-07 12:23:55 0.0009765625              1
 8 2017-09-07 12:23:56 0.0009765625              1
 9 2017-09-07 12:23:57 0.0009765625              1
10 2017-09-07 12:23:58 0.0014648438              1
```

Comment: Your example worked, but when I tried to expand it to include ~10 different time intervals, I kept getting a `lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ` error. I noticed you included three labels, but only two breaks. I scaled this up to 10 breaks and 11 labels, but was still getting this error. Does `cut()` require us to define breaks for every observation within the `df`? If  so, then the nested `ifelse()` statement is more useful for me.

Comment: Yes, you need to supply one more break value than the number of intervals you want. For example, If you want two intervals, you need to specify the endpoints plus one point in the middle, for a total of three points. (Note that I updated my answer to include three labels, hence four break points.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems easy.

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:51", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
end <- as.POSIXct("2017-09-07 12:23:55", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
df$lamp_intensity <- ifelse(start <= df$date & df$date <= end, 0, NA)
```